# What is the object that contains data in PHP multi cURL

Tags: php, curl

From the PHP manual a multi curl is performed like this:

```
    // create both cURL resources
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    $ch2 = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    //create the multiple cURL handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    //add the two handles
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

    $active = null;
    //execute the handles
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

//---------
```

Link:[http://php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

I can copy paste the code as is and it would get me the content. Notice how I don't "echo" anything, so it works without echoing.

So my question is, where does the data come from? What is the object holding the data? I know you have to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true and then get the content with `curl_multi_getcontent()` but as I stated the script retrieves content, but where is the object?

Comment: Where is what object? What do you mean by "object holding the data"?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Im not sure what I mean. The script outputs data without echoing. How is that possible?

Comment: What does the script output in your case? content of of the requested resources?

Comment: @@jedrzej.kurylo Yes exactly.

Comment: Did you set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **curl_exec** and **curl_multi_exec** output the response by default. You need to set **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** option to **true** to disable the output and make those functions return the response instead.

Comment: So multi curl "streams" the data from server to browser? How does that work? Is the data not hold inside an object for processing? ( I dont want to do CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in my code, thats why I ask)

Comment: It sends data to the output buffer the same way other functions like print() can do. The function fetches some content and then, depending on the value of CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option either prints/echos it or returns it. Why do you want to avoid setting that option? If you want to save the response to a variable instead of just printing that, you have no other choice.

Comment: Of course "the output buffer" :) Thank you very much. I want to avoid setting the option because Im developing an app and that option is slowing down the flow since it needs to gather "all" the multi content before processing other stuff

Comment: I see. Have a look at Guzzle library - it should give you more power over how the requests are sent and response processed. In general it will allow you to perform requests in a simpler and object oriented manner: http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks will look into it, looks promising